# Stop hidden cmd script

Tags: c#, cmd

I start cmd file (ftpCmdPath) in hidden mode.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process processCmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = ftpCmdPath;
    processCmd.StartInfo = startInfo;
    processCmd.Start();
```

After that I try to stop it with next logic:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd"))
{
p.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

I also tried:

```
p.Kill();
p.Close();
```

When I start the same cmd script in a mode different from Hidden everything is okay, but Hidden process always keeps working. I see with debugger that this process is still called "cmd" but nothing happens when I try to close it.

Comment: What is your ftpcmdpath ?

Comment: Can you not use `processCmd` to kill it, rather than try and find it again?  Killing all cmd processes seems potentially troublesome and overkill.

Comment: ftpCmdPath is a valid path to my script with extension cmd. As I said when I start it with another mode (not Hidden) everything works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom method to list all process that have cmd as parent process

You need to add System.Management reference first.

Then simply kill the process tree:

```
void Main()
        {

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c notepad");
        var cmdProcess = Process.Start(psi);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        KillProcessAndChildren(cmdProcess.Id);

    }

    public void KillProcessAndChildren(int pid)
    {
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
        ("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid))
    {
        var moc = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            KillProcessAndChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
        }
        try
        {
            var proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
            proc.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Process already exited.
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I already know the name is "cmd". I checked it with debugger in flying mode.

Comment: I have changed the response.